# How to display multiple windows independently?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm writing a GUI, and I want to open multiple windows with same interface and independent. But I when I try to input in one window, and another one shows the same thing, how to make the windows independent? Example:

```
foreach name {test1 test2} {
    namespace eval $name {
        variable InputStr
        variable wid
        proc Display {var} {
            variable InputStr
            variable wid 
            set wid .$var

            destroy $wid
            toplevel $wid

            wm title $wid $var
            entry $wid.en -textvariable InputStr 
            pack $wid.en
        }
    }   
    ${name}::Display $name
}
```

Why they are dependent? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Interesting code with a solid "Tcl flavor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an unqualified variable name, the entry widget assumes the variable is a global and uses the same variable in both cases. Try

```
entry $wid.en -textvariable [namespace current]::InputStr
```

or

```
entry $wid.en -textvariable $var\::InputStr
```

which should be the same thing, given the definitions in the question.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That's really helpful.